# How to remove URLs from text file when URL's status is followed by 4xx,5xx

Tags: python, python-requests

I wanted to make requests to the URLs from a text file and then remove the URL's; having status code followed by 4xx,5xx. I have already coded that first part that is making requests to the URLs from the text file. Now only the problem I am having is how would I remove the specific URL?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import requests
file_inp = open("test.txt","r")
emptylist = []
for i in file_inp:
    emptylist.append(i)

for i in emptylist:
    check = requests.get(i)
    statuss = check.status_code
    if statuss == 4xx or check.status_code == 3xx:
        #Want to remove these url's from my test file
else:
    print("200 OK")
```

I would really appreciate your help since I'm a beginner :)

Comment: You need to delete the corresponding `emptylist` entries and write `emptylist` back to your original text file. `emptylist.remove(i)` would do. But please choose more meaningful names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write the URLs having status code not equal to 4xx or 5xx into different file instead of deleting the same from existing file. Please refer below,

```
f_out = open('output_file_name.txt', 'w')
for i in emptylist: 
    check = requests.get(i) 
    statuss = check.status_code
    if statuss == 4xx or statuss == 5xx:
        f_out.write(i)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How about if I do a check for the status 200 only and write them of a sperate file. Just like `if statuss == 200:
        f_out.write(i)`

Comment: Additionally, assuming there would be thousand URL's to be tested for the status:200. Making requests for each would take a lot of time. Any Idea/Tip how would I increase the efficiency of the task?

Comment: Yes, of course, u can go ahead with checking the status code 200 only as you want to filter the valid URLs only.

Comment: Keep writing all the valid URLs into the file instead of accumulating in the memory so that the memory can be utilized efficiently.